# G3 Usb Modem Huawei E1550 did not work after unplug (NetworkManager)

Tags: networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

I have the following problem:
When I boot with plugged in usb modem everything is fine.
If I unplug modem and plug it back it can not be used any more.

Some logs below.

**1. Modem plugged on boot**

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

**usb_modeswitch log:**

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Sun Apr 08 23:38:27 CEST 2012
Raw args from udev: /1-1.1:1.0
Using global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
Using top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  manufacturer  HUAWEI Technology
  product   HUAWEI Mobile
  serial    
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
SCSI attributes not needed, moving on
checking config: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/12d1:1446
! matched. Reading config data
config: TargetVendor set to 12d1
config: TargetProductList set to 1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
Command to be run:
usb_modeswitch -I -W -D -s 20 -u -1 -b 1 -g 9 -v 12d1 -p 1446 -f $configBuffer

Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are to be expected in the process)
--------------------------------

Reading long config from command line

* usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes  
* Version 1.2.1 (C) Josua Dietze 2011
* Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1446
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    not set
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506"

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=0
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
QisdaMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
SequansMode=0
MobileActionMode=0
CiscoMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set
InquireDevice disabled
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled
Use given bus/device number: 001/009 ...
Looking for default devices ...
 bus/device number matched
 searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
 found matching vendor ID
 found matching product ID
 adding device
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
 Skipping the check for the current configuration
 Using first interface: 0x00
 Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
 USB description data (for identification)
 -------------------------
 Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
     Serial No.: not provided
 -------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
OK, driver found; name unknown, limitation of libusb1
OK, driver "unkown" detached
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
libusb:error [op_clear_halt] clear_halt failed error -1 errno 71
OK, message successfully sent
Resetting response endpoint 0x81
Resetting message endpoint 0x01
 Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -34
 Device is gone, skipping any further commands
 Bus/dev search active, referring success check to wrapper. Bye.
 ok:busdev
 --------------------------------
 (end of usb_modeswitch output)
Checking success of mode switch for max. 20 seconds ...
 Waiting for device file system (1 sec.) ...
 Waiting for device file system (15 sec.) ...
Reading attributes ...
All attributes matched
Mode switching was successful, found 12d1:1001 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Now checking for newly created ports ...
 new ports found, device is known to driver
Checking for AVOID_RESET_QUIRK kernel attribute
AVOID_RESET_QUIRK activated
All done, exiting
```

**2.Modem unplugged and plugged back**

**lsusb**
    Bus 001 Device 008: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem

**usb_modeswitch log:**

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Sun Apr 08 23:46:12 CEST 2012

Raw args from udev: /1-1.1:1.0

Using global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
Using top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
manufacturer    HUAWEI Technology
product HUAWEI Mobile
serial  
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
SCSI attributes not needed, moving on
checking config: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/12d1:1446
! matched. Reading config data
config: TargetVendor set to 12d1
config: TargetProductList set to 1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
Command to be run:
usb_modeswitch -I -W -D -s 20 -u -1 -b 1 -g 7 -v 12d1 -p 1446 -f $configBuffer
Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are to be expected in the process)
--------------------------------
Reading long config from command line
 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 1.2.1 (C) Josua Dietze 2011
 * Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)
! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1446
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    not set
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506"

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=0
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
QisdaMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
SequansMode=0
MobileActionMode=0
CiscoMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set

InquireDevice disabled
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled

Use given bus/device number: 001/007 ...
Looking for default devices ...
  bus/device number matched
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1446
  found matching vendor ID
  found matching product ID
  adding device
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Skipping the check for the current configuration
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
 Product: HUAWEI Mobile
 Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
OK, driver found; name unknown, limitation of libusb1
OK, driver "unkown" detached
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
libusb:error [op_clear_halt] clear_halt failed error -1 errno 71
OK, message successfully sent
Resetting response endpoint 0x81
Resetting message endpoint 0x01
Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -34
Device is gone, skipping any further commands
Bus/dev search active, referring success check to wrapper. Bye.
ok:busdev
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)

Checking success of mode switch for max. 20 seconds ...
 Waiting for device file system (1 sec.) ...
 Waiting for device file system (15 sec.) ...
```

Reading attributes ...
   All attributes matched
   Mode switching was successful, found 12d1:1001 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
   Now checking for newly created ports ...
    new ports found, device is known to driver
    Checking for AVOID_RESET_QUIRK kernel attribute
    AVOID_RESET_QUIRK activated
    All done, exiting

**dmesg output:**

```
[  261.611314] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  283.800711] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[  283.899855] scsi11 : usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
[  283.900156] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-1.1:1.1
[  284.638710] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  300.687875] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[  300.787664] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  300.788085] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  300.788450] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  300.789174] scsi16 : usb-storage 1-1.1:1.3
[  300.790242] scsi17 : usb-storage 1-1.1:1.4
```

P.S. I am using NetworkManager 0.9.2.0, Arch Linux, XFCE

**Update: Test on Xubuntu 11.10 Live CD**

I have just tested it under Xubuntu.

- After booting I have plugged-in USB modem.

  - Modem was immediately recognized  by the system and start working
- I have unplugged it and plugged it back.

  - Modem was recognized and working.

**dmesg output**

```
[  902.454378] usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
[  902.562241] scsi14 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  902.562632] scsi15 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.1
[  903.278564] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  919.341096] usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[  919.450088] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  919.450301] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  919.450597] option 1-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  919.450739] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  919.450984] option 1-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  919.451123] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  919.454323] scsi19 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.3
[  919.459118] scsi20 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.4
[  920.456207] scsi 19:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  920.460283] scsi 20:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  920.749708] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[  920.749847] sr 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  920.749937] sr 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  920.752303] sd 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  920.761650] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I would say, that dmesg output from Xbuntu  looks similar to one from Arch.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can boot a current live-cd of a well tested distribution that uses binary packages (like Fedora or Ubuntu) to check if your problem is Arch specific.

Comment: @maxschlepzig I have made a test under Xubuntu. Looks like it works. See above.